# GSON JSON serialization - Unable to make field private int java.sql.Timestamp.nanos accessible

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, sybase

Since a recent Java upgrade we are failing to serialize an object read from a SQL database with values mapped to `java.sql.Timestamp`. The underlying database is a SAP Sybase and our customer was able to reproduce the problem with a query as simple as `Select getdate()`.

Environment: Java 17.0.4.1, Eclipse Adoptium, Mac OS X 14.0

It's not an option for us to add `add-opens=java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED` or similar. I also tried to debug into the `TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper` in the Gson library and found that a "reflective adapter" is being used for the `java.sql.Timestamp` object.

As a workaround, I'm now using the Jackson library as a fallback which is able to serialize my object without problems (i.e. the second try clause in the code below works without issues):

```
try {
    json = GSON.toJson(object);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Failed to serialize JSON. Trying alternative serializer (1).", e);
    try {
        json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        log.warn("Failed to serialize JSON. Leaving null.", e);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.sql.Timestamp#nanos' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:55)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:144)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:842)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:812)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:759)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:736)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private int java.sql.Timestamp.nanos accessible: module java.sql does not "opens java.sql" to unnamed module @2554782d
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How should the json of such a serialized timestamp look like?

Comment: Is this `JavaFX`? See if the `module-info.java` information can help you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70302970/2423906)

Comment: Gson [should have a dedicated adapter for `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/sql/SqlTypesSupport.java), but maybe the logic in Gson is flawed and for some reason it is not applied? Could you please debug and check how the internal Gson class `SqlTypesSupport` behaves for you? Though, the format used by Gson's built-in adapter might not be desired, so you might want to write a [custom adapter](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to write your own TypeAdapter. Or add an exclusion for specific types that failed. Found that in a troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/Troubleshooting.md#-inaccessibleobjectexception-module--does-not-opens--to-unnamed-module
Having the exact error, your workaround looks fine too.